# Performance issue :Angular JS showing script in html page

Tags: angularjs

When I call a rest service then i will get .html file from server. But it showing scripts for 1 or 2 seconds. Then it shows correct values.My problem is page loads first then controller binds data. Is there is any way to bind data before loading page?  [image]

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two options that I know of:

1. The preferred option is to add ng-cloak to sections of the page that contain angular templates. From the docs:

   `<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
   <div id="template2" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">{{ 'hello IE7' }}</div>`
2. Use ng-bind instead of the `{{ }}` approach. For example:

   `<div ng-bind="marked4Reviewcount"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ngCloak directive. It temporarily hides the Angular template while the page is being loaded. You could apply it on the body tag, but it's advised to do it on portions of the page so you get a progressive loading effect.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Comment: Well, without knowing what you're doing, I'm taking some guesses here... 1. Is your angular script file include being done in the head section of your page? It's advised to do so in the Angular documentation.. 2. Which version of Angular are you using?